# Material Design: Button or Edit Text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, semantics, android-button, material-design

I have a question about Material Design and semantics.
I try to make the settings of my application and I have only a few fields. So I first try to make the UI like this one, with a `LinearLayout` and some `EditText`:

[image: Capitain Train EditText]

I have to set hour, and I have set `OnClickListener` to display a `TimePickerDialog`.

But when I check the settings on Google Agenda, it appear to be a List of `Button`? (The animation on touch is the same on `Button`)

[image: Google Agenda Buttons]

Should I use `Button` and not `EditText`? Even if it's look like FullWidth Textfield?

Should I use a `List` rather than `LinearLayout`?

I am sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both approach but if you will use Linear layout that will be good.

For material design you can follow below link:

1. https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#flat-button
2. https://github.com/keithellis/MaterialWidget
3. https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar
4. https://github.com/madcyph3r/AdvancedMaterialDrawer

I hope, It will help.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I indeed use navasmdc's library, and other tools like [MaterialNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer) and [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib). It helps a lot. Especially for compatibility. I will use `LinearLayout`. Did you think I should use Button or EditText? Because the view's content (the text) is user modifiable.

Comment: you should use EditText not button.

Comment: if my ans was useful for you then please click as right answer and click for useful ans.